# ¿Por qué el cura Hidalgo usó el vosotros?

Tags: diferencias-regionales, historia, méxico, religión

> ¿Habéis tomado el gusto al sabroso licor que exprimís de las mamilas de vuestras vacas, sin el azar de que el comerciante ultramarino que os fió cuatro andrajos podrá venir a echaros un embargo sobre esas mismas reses que a costa de sudores habéis criado y cuidado a fuerza de desvelos continuados? ¿No es verdad que muchos de vosotros ignoráis lo dulce que es al paladar la miel que fabrican las abejas?

En 1810-1811, el cura revolucionario Miguel Hidalgo luchó en México contra el imperio español. Él fue un criollo de México y me sorprendió ver que en esta [proclamación](http://www.memoriapoliticademexico.org/Textos/1Independencia/1810-PP-MH-PIP.html) eligió usar el vosotros. Ví algunas otras de él y tenían lo mismo. Su presentación es formal, es decir, bien compuesta y seria. No sé como hablaba en la iglesia. Claro que las proclamaciones se entendían, pero ¿porqué se hicieron así?

Hidalgo se conoce principalmente por oponer a España, pero en este caso él eligió una forma de hablar que (por lo menos hoy) es marcadamente ligada a la peninsula. El reemplazo del vosotros supuestamente se debe a los peninsulares andaluces que no lo usaban tampoco (del tesis de Víctor Lara Bermejo, "El uso de ustedes por vosotros en Andalucía occidental").

Además de esa desubicación, quizás menos grave en la época, Hidalgo eligió dirigir palabras al pueblo en el modo informal. Yo habría pensado que mostrar respeto máximo hacia la audiencia sería una clave a su buena reacción, pero parece que no. Siendo él muy convencedor -- muchos lo siguieron al campo de batalla -- su modo retórico debía ser muy considerado, y soy yo que no lo entiendo.

**¿Qué quiso señalar Hidalgo con su uso del vosotros?**

[image: Detalle del retablo de Juan O'Gorman]

Answer (score 1):

Iba a escribir únicamente un comentario, pero se me estaba yendo de extensión.

Nótese que el empleo de **ustedes** por vosotros no implica necesariamente una mayor cortesía aquí en Andalucía desde donde escribo.

El texto me parece correcto. Si a posteriori, meses o años después del discurso, se ha destacado la diferencia entre vosotros/ustedes como un rasgo diferenciador frente al opresor imperio de la metrópoli con **fines nacionalistas** es agua de otro cantar.

En resumen, en mi opinión **no quiso indicar nada especial**.

Muestras de desmesurado aprecio y cortesía hacia el pueblo llano pueden tener el efecto contrario, que las declaraciones se tomen acertadamente como chufla y escarnio:

> Sus señorías maeses ganaderos, han tomado vuecencias ilustrisimas el gusto al sabroso licor ...

Como nota aparte, los pobres mexicanos cambiaron a ese comerciante (¿banquero?) ultramarino por otro autóctono y no ganaron mucho. Véanse las posteriores revoluciones, como las encabezadas por Villa y Zapata.

Comment: Gracias por proponer esta explicación. En cuanto de la edad del rasgo nacionalista, ¿creemos que el vosotros se usaba a menudo en el México de 1810?

Comment: @AaronBrick Me temo que no soy lingüista. Como digo, mi post es más un comentario largo que propiamente una respuesta. No puedo responder a esta segunda pregunta que me haces.